# При удалении элемента списка и смещении остальных элементов влево значение нулевого(по индексу) элемента не меняется

Tags: python

```
def f(l):
    for i,v in enumerate(l):
        print(i,v)
        if i == 0:
            l.remove(i)
            print(l)
            print(i,v)
            l.append(i)
            print(l)
l = [0,1,2,3]
print(f(l))

>>>
0 0
[1, 2, 3]
0 0
[1, 2, 3, 0]
1 2
2 3
3 0
None
```

Скажите, почему на первой итерации цикла после удаления первого элемента (0) список изменился а индекс и значение остались от прежнего элемента? Ведь, по идее, т.к. из-за смещения элементов влево произошла замена и теперь у нас нулевой (по индексу) элемент другой (1), что мы и видим принтуя список, значит и значение нулевого (по индексу) элемента должно измениться. Тем не менее, питон говорит, что значение не изменилось и использует это значение далее в коде.
Спасибо!

Comment: все как написано, так и работает. Покажите результат, который вы хотите получить.

Answer (score 2):

Потому что в цикле for будет храниться копия списка
но не сам список, в итерации вы удаляете элемент из списка а в копии он остается. Чтобы это решить воспользуйтесь циклом while

Answer (score 1):

Разберем по порядку ваш код.

Определяем функцию и пробегаемся по списку. В директиве `for` вы определяете две переменные `i` и `v`. Что буквально означает `i` - позиция в списке, `v` - значение ([enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate))

```
def f(l):
    for i,v in enumerate(l):
        print(i,v)
```

Так вот вопрос: когда данные переменные изменят свое значение? Ответ: тогда и только тогда, когда будут присвоены новые. Присвоение произойдет только в следующей итерации по `for`.

Далее пошагово:

```py
...
        if i == 0:        # Позиция равна нулю? -> True
            l.remove(i)   # Удалить по значению (Важно!!!), а не по позиции. 
                          # в данном случае у вас позиция и значения равны
            print(l)      # [1, 2, 3]
            print(i,v)    # переопределены переменные? нет! значит вывод этих 
                          # переменных будет абслютно таким же как и в самом начале
                          # 0 0
            l.append(i)   # Добавить значение 0 (не позиция, а именно значение)
            print(l)      # [1, 2, 3, 0]
```

Это была первая (нулевая) итерация. Что же дальше? А ничего, будут меняться только значения переменных `i` и `v` и выводиться в консоль. Больше ни разу не сработают директивы под `if`

Comment: вот мне и не понятно почему переменные не переопределяются, ведь список то изменился и питон явно об этом сообщает print(l) [1,2,3]

Comment: Сам список изменился, а переменные то нет в данной итерации. Они поменяются только когда вы им скажете поменяться либо в следующей итерации

Comment: ну то есть переменные сами по себе, а список сам по себе, вроде бы начинает доходить, спасибо!